# What happened to Glimpse v2?

Tags: glimpse

Currently the version of Glimpse.Core on NuGet is 1.8.6. There is a really nice feature in v2 - GlimpseTimeline - that I'd like to take advantage of, but although I can find references to Glimpse v2 as far back as September 2013 and v2 is on GitHub it doesn't look like the NuGet package is being updated. Should I just bite the bullet and compile the project locally or are there plans to get v2 up on NuGet at some point?

Comment: I would suggest [filing this on the project's GitHub Issues page instead of on SO](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues).

Comment: @Lex v2 is still a work in progress, you can always compile it locally but it wouldn't run stable as it isn't finished yet.

Comment: Glimpse v2 beta has just been released

Comment: I saw that. Unfortunately it only supports ASP.NET 5 right now.